# macOS app crashes and does not prompt for camera permissions

Tags: ios, macos, permissions, camera, info.plist

My app works fine in any other macOS version except in Catalina. I have added the camera and microphone permissions in the Info.plist file as explained [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/cameras_and_media_capture/requesting_authorization_for_media_capture_on_macos) but the app keeps crashing when it should prompt for permissions (I've even tried to add every single available permission that XCode provides). If I run my app from the terminal it actually prompts with "Terminal" would like to access the camera.

Any idea with this? Here is part of the log:

```
Process:               FooApp [1761]
Path:                  /Applications/FooApp.app/Contents/Home/bin/./FooApp
Identifier:            com.fooApp
Version:               1.6.0.3 (1.6.0.3)
Code Type:             X86-64 (Native)
Parent Process:        ??? [1757]
User ID:               501

Date/Time:             2019-12-03 13:53:30.472 +0100
OS Version:            Mac OS X 10.15.1 (19B88)
Report Version:        12
Anonymous UUID:        0FEAB303-C00B-E970-1979-5CE1CC615C4E


Time Awake Since Boot: 3100 seconds

System Integrity Protection: disabled

Crashed Thread:        19  Dispatch queue: com.apple.root.default-qos

Exception Type:        EXC_CRASH (SIGKILL)
Exception Codes:       0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Exception Note:        EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY

Termination Reason:    Namespace TCC, Code 0x0

Thread 19 Crashed:: Dispatch queue: com.apple.root.default-qos
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff6377c15e __terminate_with_payload + 10
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff63796512 abort_with_payload_wrapper_internal + 119
2   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff6379651d abort_with_payload + 9
3   com.apple.TCC                   0x00007fff5b9060d1 __CRASHING_DUE_TO_PRIVACY_VIOLATION__ + 163
4   com.apple.TCC                   0x00007fff5b90602e __TCCAccessRequest_block_invoke.114 + 500
5   com.apple.TCC                   0x00007fff5b903bc5 __tccd_send_message_block_invoke + 231
6   libxpc.dylib                    0x00007fff63879ef4 _xpc_connection_reply_callout + 36
7   libxpc.dylib                    0x00007fff63879e7c _xpc_connection_call_reply_async + 69
8   libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fff635dc578 _dispatch_client_callout3 + 8
9   libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fff635f3080 _dispatch_mach_msg_async_reply_invoke + 369
10  libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fff635eb48c _dispatch_kevent_worker_thread + 1324
11  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff63835763 _pthread_wqthread + 362
12  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff6383557b start_wqthread + 15

Thread 20:: Dispatch queue: com.apple.root.default-qos
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff6377a4a2 __wait4 + 10
1   libmonosgen-2.0.1.dylib         0x000000010e87fecd mono_handle_native_crash + 397
2   libsystem_platform.dylib        0x00007fff6382db1d _sigtramp + 29
3   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff636ece1b __v2printf + 475
4   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff6379651d abort_with_payload + 9
5   com.apple.TCC                   0x00007fff5b9060d1 __CRASHING_DUE_TO_PRIVACY_VIOLATION__ + 163
6   com.apple.TCC                   0x00007fff5b90602e __TCCAccessRequest_block_invoke.114 + 500
7   com.apple.TCC                   0x00007fff5b903bc5 __tccd_send_message_block_invoke + 231
8   libxpc.dylib                    0x00007fff63879ef4 _xpc_connection_reply_callout + 36
9   libxpc.dylib                    0x00007fff63879e7c _xpc_connection_call_reply_async + 69
10  libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fff635dc578 _dispatch_client_callout3 + 8
11  libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fff635f3080 _dispatch_mach_msg_async_reply_invoke + 369
12  libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fff635eb48c _dispatch_kevent_worker_thread + 1324
13  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff63835763 _pthread_wqthread + 362
14  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff6383557b start_wqthread + 15
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally, after no help on the whole Internet I found that the problem is that the program that Info.plist uses to open my application is a script that sets up some needed stuff and then opens the program.

The error here is that my application is not using the Info.plist file for the application opened with the script since the script is the owner of that file. Then the application crashes since it has no Info.plist file where getting the message to prompt for permissions.

In my case I had to create a unix executable with mono `mkbundle` as the major change.

I wrote a post about packaging in macOS where I explain this here: https://www.theimpostersyndrome.dev/posts/macospackaging/

Answer (score 0):

Did you try give access from settings? Some apps doesn't support New Mac OS Version. So when it trying request an access something it crashing

Comment: Thanks for your response Ahmet, but this does not help me. I have given access from settings to my app for "Accessibility", "Input Monitoring", "Full Disk Access" and "Developer Tools" (I can not give acces for example to "Camera" because the system does not give me that option).

Answer (score 0):

1. in your terminal type `:launchctl list|grep -i com.apple.tccd`
2. if there are nothing try type: `launchctl load -wF /System/Library/LaunchAgents/com.apple.tccd.plist`
3. restart your mac

Comment: Hi Spud. Please can you explain which this is the solution.

Comment: Back in the office right now. This does not work for me. Also, I don't know how that can be the solution.